# List items added in datagrid but not displaying on the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, viewmodel

I have added the listItems to datagrid view. But the problem is even the list items are part of datagrid.item but the are not displaying on the screen.
This is the data grid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DeviceListView" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  
ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceList}" Width="1403" / >
```

This how I added it

```
DeviceListView.ItemsSource = DeviceList;
```

Items in list are declared as properties and are public.and list is list of the object of below class
The class has below three property

```
Class device { 
        public string DeviceType { get; set; }
        public string devname { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This data grid is part of view which iam loading on my main window of wpf app.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to deal with that is using an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0

Any item added to the ObservableCollection automatically reflects on the UI.

Comment: changed it  but the solution is not working for me
I have mainWindow in it i have a contextcontrol where iam loading a view on click of button. the view is loading empty and i have no idea what iam doing incorrect